# jQuery selector for element with numeric id using CSS escapes

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to give a red color to a div id='1' class='std' using jQuery (i equals 1):

```
$("#" + i).css("background-color", "red");
```

code snippet:

```
           for(var i=0 ; i< info.length ; i++ ){

                var div_std ='<div id="'+i+'" class="std"> <p> Name :<b> '+info[i].nom_etud + ' </b></p> <hr><p> Abs Hours : '+info[i].hr_cours +'</p>' ;
                div_std+='<p> TPs Hours : '+info[i].hr_tp+'</p><section id="footstd"><button type="button" name="">Mark as absent</button><img src="images/abs.png"></section>'+'</div>';            

                if(info[i].col == 1)
                {
                    $(function() {
                      $("#\\" + i.toString().charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).css("background", "red");
                    });
                }
                else if(info[i].col == 2)
                    $(function() {
                      $("#\\" + i.toString().charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).css("background", "blue");
                    });
                else if(info[i].col == 3)
                    $(function() {
                      $("#\\" + i.toString().charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).css("background", "green");
                    });
                $(".main").append(div_std);   //Display the students name
            }
```

Comment: can you show the <tag> that you declare your id ? ex.
<div id="1" .....></div>

Comment: yeah sorry: it's a div.

Comment: are you sure, you are writing your code inside $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#" + i).css("background-color", "red");
})

Comment: Make sure your code is executed after the DOM is ready, i.e. write your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`  
 this may fix issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match ids that start with numbers or special characters you should use [CSS escapes](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes):

```js
$(function() {
  // #1 should be escaped as #\31
  $("#\\31").css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">div</div>
```

And this is a lengthier example for ids 1 ... 100:

```js
$(function() {
  var i, selector, $div;
  for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    selector = "#\\" + i.toString().charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + " " + i.toString().substr(1);
    $div = $('<div id="' + i + '"><code>id: ' + i + ', selector: ' + selector + '</code></div>').appendTo("body");
    $(selector).css("background", "green");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Having said that, in your case you can simply use inline styles to change the background color instead of using CSS selectors:

```
var bgcolor = ["red", "blue", "green"][info[i].col - 1] || "transparent";
var div_std = '<div id="' + i + '" class="std" style="background-color: ' + bgcolor + '">...'
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what does '\\000031' mean?

Comment: @DeveloperX you need to look at linked article. In particular, in order to use special characters in CSS selectors you must escape them. For this you need a ```\``` followed by hex representation of the unicode codepoint number. You can generate the escape sequence using JavaScript (see example 2).

Comment: $("#\\" + i.toString().charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).css("background", "green"); is not working

Comment: when I print out the value of 'i' to the screen it shows '1' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I edited my post so that you can see the code I'm working on.

Comment: "*[You] need to look at linked article*" - no, you need to include the essential parts of the external resource in your answer, to guard against link-rot and prevent this answer becoming useless if the circumstances of future users, looking to this question, should be different.

Comment: @DavidThomas I've changed the link to w3.org.

Comment: So? My point still stands: please include the relevant portions of the external resource to enable this answer to stand alone. By all means link to the W3 as part of a reference, or bibliography, but your answer should still be meaningful without that reference.

Comment: @DeveloperX see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`ID`s cannot start with a number for `#` `CSS` selectors.](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Here's how you need to do:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div[id='+i+']').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

---

**Edit**

My bad, `#1` doesn't work in `CSS` but does with `jQuery` ([as per @GuilhermeOderdenge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327166/2788131)). As such, there's no need for using `$('div[id=1]')`.

Comment: Wrap your code inside `jQuery(function($) { });` or put the code **after** your div. Works locally.

Answer (score 1):

As @D4V1D said, it's impossible to access `#1` through CSS, but with jQuery you can—even in a flat way, without `div[id=x]`. See:

```
var i = 1;

$('#' + i).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Try yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/wn7njfuc/

If the solution isn't working for you, probably your jQuery wasn't launched seamlessly.

#### EDIT 1

According to OP's comment, he is using Jade. So, try this just before your div:

```
script.
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var i = 1;
      $('#' + i).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
```

Comment: How can this is even possible? I can only see jQuery here, where's javascript?

Comment: I can see that it's working, but what do you mean by 'jQuery wasn't launched' ?

Comment: @D4V1D JavaScript is all around, mate. Furthermore, you are right—`.querySelector` doesn't support `#1`, but Sizzle/jQuery Selector Engine does. Anyway, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DeveloperX Well, if the `background-color` isn't being applied, something is happening—probably jQuery isn't working well or wasn't called in your file, because you have the code you need to get this feature done.

Comment: the div which I'm trying to give a color to is inside a jade file, which is a block content inside another jade file. I verified that I do include jQuery in my jade container.

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is being included? See my update. Also, if still not working, please, update your question with more details—such as your template itself.