# Change the class selector to id select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

I have some `input type="file"` with which the user can publish images. There will be multiple `input` so I  have to change this script, previously formed from a single input so created with a *class selector*, to a multiple `input`. I thought to put the id. But it doesn't work yet. Why?

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

      $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('.file-upload-content').show();

      $('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  } else {
    removeUpload();
  }
}

function removeUpload() {
  $('.file-upload-input').replaceWith($('.file-upload-input').clone());
  $('.file-upload-content').hide();
  $('.image-upload-wrap').show();
}
$('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragover', function () {
  $('.image-upload-wrap').addClass('image-dropping');
 });
 $('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragleave', function () {
  $('.image-upload-wrap').removeClass('image-dropping');
 });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.file-upload {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.file-upload-btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1FB264;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #15824B;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.file-upload-btn:hover {
  background: #1AA059;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload-btn:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.file-upload-content {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.file-upload-input {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-upload-wrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 4px dashed #D2D2D2;
  position: relative;
}

.image-dropping,
.image-upload-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #1FB264;
  border: 4px dashed #D2D2D2;
}

.image-title-wrap {
  padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
  color: #222;
}

.drag-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.drag-text h3 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #15824B;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.file-upload-image {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.remove-image {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #cd4535;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #b02818;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.remove-image:hover {
  background: #c13b2a;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-image:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-upload">
      
  <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('#1').trigger( 'click' )">Add Image</button>
  <div class="image-upload-wrap" id="1">
    <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
    <div class="drag-text">
      <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload-content">
    <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div class="image-title-wrap">
      <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('#2').trigger( 'click' )">Add Image</button>
  <div class="image-upload-wrap" id="2">
    <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
    <div class="drag-text">
      <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload-content">
    <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div class="image-title-wrap">
      <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
      
    <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('#3').trigger( 'click' )">Add Image</button>
  <div class="image-upload-wrap" id="3">
    <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
    <div class="drag-text">
      <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload-content">
    <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div class="image-title-wrap">
      <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
          <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('#4').trigger( 'click' )">Add Image</button>
  <div class="image-upload-wrap" id="4">
    <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
    <div class="drag-text">
      <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload-content">
    <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div class="image-title-wrap">
      <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Currently, as you can see, if you upload a photo will be equal in all other fields.

Comment: The id must begin with a letter, not a number, as per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: @LcLk Not completely true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327060/jquery-selector-for-element-with-numeric-id-using-css-escapes

Comment: I wrote a letter in the id but it still doesn't work

Comment: I wasn't aware of escaping css selectors. Thanks for the link @mplungjan . But I doubt I'll use them, sticking to convention instead of escaping characters is easier :)

Comment: I completely agree. Just posted the link for completeness' sake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your code relevant to the container of the image you are engaged with. Currently you change looks of all elements with same class and therefore see same thing in all containers.

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/9tbfL55o/)

For your `onload` function use this:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
   var $parent = $(input).parent(),
       $nextEl = $parent.next();

   $parent.hide();
   $nextEl.find('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
   $nextEl.show();
   $nextEl.find('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
};
```

For your `removeUpload` function use this:

```
function removeUpload(button) {
   var $parent = $(button).parent().parent();

   $parent.hide();
   $parent.prev().show();
}
```

And change the onclick function call for remove buttons to `onclick="removeUpload(this)"` to pass the clicked button to function.

Comment: Wow, super!! Thank you very much!