# How to replace text in a "td" element based on row id and th name/index using JQuery or Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my current data:

```
<tr id="1">
<th>Name</th>
<td>John</td>
<th>Country</th>
<td>US</td>
</tr>
```

I tried the following:

```
let rowID = 1;
let columnTitle = "Country";
$('#'+rowID+' td:eq('+columnTitle+')').html("Japan");
```

Here is what I expect:

```
<tr id="1">
<th>Name</th>
<td>John</td>
<th>Country</th>
<td>Japan</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To select an element with a purely numerical ID, you would need to apply escaping in the CSS selector - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327474/1427878

Comment: `td:eq('+columnTitle+')` - [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selects based on element index, not text content. (And even if it did the latter, the element containing "Country" in your example is a `th`, not a `td`. Plus, you would be selecting the third td/th, whereas the value you want to manipulate, is in the fourth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the next `td` HTML after the `th` which contains `country`, you need to modify your code like the below:

```
$("#" + rowID + ' th:contains(' + columnName + ')').next('td').html("Japan");
```

Working sample:

```js
let rowID = 1;
let columnName = "Country";

$("#" + rowID + ' th:contains(' + columnName + ')').next('td').html("Japan");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>John</td>
    <th>Country</th>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

with JQuery you can do this approach:

```
let rowID = 1;
let columnName = "Country";

// and the fun part is here
$(`#${rowID} th:contains('${columnName}')`).next('td').text("Japan");
```